# Использование cookie при развертывании приложения в Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, cookie, nuxt.js

Написано универсальное веб приложение(Nuxt SSR + firebase), в нем у меня используются cookie, как для хранения токена так и другие. Локально при сборке проекта все отрабатывает отлично. Только разворачиваю на хостинге Firebase, сайт работает но при перезагрузке страницы, будто cookie игнорируются, хотя они там есть.

Из-за специфики SSR не могу использовать для этих целей обычный localStorage, использую пакеты **cookie** и **cookie-js**.
Прочитал следущее из документации Firebase:

> При использовании Firebase Hosting вместе с Cloud Functions или Cloud Run файлы cookie обычно удаляются из входящих запросов. Это необходимо для обеспечения эффективного поведения кеша CDN. Только специально названный __session cookie __session может передаваться на выполнение вашего приложения.

Как мне быть тогда в этом случае, если у меня несколько cookie необходимых для работы? Может кто сталкивался с подобным.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел информацию, что объект window доступен в хуке mounted, где могу обратиться к localStorage, в куке "__session" оставил токен, остальное храню в локальном хранилище на клиенте.